# What is the theory regarding how far back the Vedic chants were first composed into the rigid memorization system?

Tags: vedas, vedic-chanting

I saw on [Quora someone suggesting](https://qr.ae/pKTEBa) that the chants/texts *content* reference some geographical features stretching back at least 50,000 years ago, maybe as far back as 500,000 years ago. Now, the [Vedic chant wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_chant) doesn't say much, but the [Vedas page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas) says:

> The bulk of the Rigveda Samhita was composed in the northwestern region (Punjab) of the Indian subcontinent, most likely between c. 1500 and 1200 BCE...

To have 100's of thousands of words composed, formulated into a memory system, seems like it would take longer than 1 person to create, maybe spanning many generations (though it says Vyasa is the author, so I'm speculating). To come up with all this content seems like it would have to also have evolved over long periods. According to [archaeology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peopling_of_India), people didn't reach India til 65,000 years ago. There were 2 migrations out of Africa, 1 120,000 years ago, and 1 60,000 years go, so maybe it was a mixture of genes from both migrations, I don't know. Maybe, too, the content was mentally composed and collected as they migrated, so it's not necessarily like they composed it all in the India-ish region, again, speculation.

So my question is, what are the theories on how this was composed? Like in Judaism, the religion says [someone specific](https://www.gotquestions.org/Bible-authors.html) (I forget) composed the Torah/Bible, or like Genesis is said to be composed by [Moses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Genesis) in the religion, but academia says there might have been at least [4 authors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_hypothesis) in a different timeframe. So I'm wondering both from a religious and an academic/scientific perspective, when and how were the vedas first composed, before they were written down?

Comment: "religious and an academic/scientific perspective", regarding academic/scientific perspective you should ask this question on History SE..  for authors regarding reglious perspective.. it was not 1-2-3 people who heard the mantra and told it.. there are thousands of Rishis who heard Vedic mantra and those mantra compiled forms Veda... also Rishis aren't considered author, they just hear mantra (in their meditation).. and in every cycle of creation there will be some Rishi who hears the mantra and passes it down..